# how can I edit my own map in gazebo 2.2?

Tags: ros, gazebo, navigation, mapping, create

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ros Users:

I have just created a map in gazebo 2.2. i have saved, but i want to edit now. How can i edit? because I cant see any options in gazebo "building  editor" to edit my map that i created.

Any ideas?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210866/how-can-i-edit-my-own-map-in-gazebo-2.2?/) by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2015-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
This is more of a Gazebo question (http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/) 
What you should do is open your world: 
 `roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch world_name:=YOUR_WORLD_FILE`
Then you modify it (add objects etc)
Finally save your world again.

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2015-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2021-01-29**:
can I edit existing map?